# Laravel zoom error "{"reason":"unsupported grant type","error":"unsupported_grant_type"}" Following code

Tags: laravel, http, zoom-sdk

This is my code (https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8Kwx.png)

I sending code all require parameters when I sent request from postman it works fine. but when I call this api using php or in laravel I get an error "{"reason":"unsupported grant type","error":"unsupported_grant_type"}"

Comment: Please post code, not screenshots. You might consider using the Zoom Socialite integration; https://socialiteproviders.com/Zoom/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.